# Windows SmartScreen Blocks My EXE File. Any Solutions?

Tags: java, windows, exe, smartscreen

I've been working on an online game for a while now and I've recently decided that I want to share it with some of my friends for testing. Now I decided that I want to make an installer for it, just to make it easier/fancier to get the game. I originally wrote it in Java and used Launch4j and Inno Setup to make my setup.exe but when I initially run it, windows smartscreen thinks it could be dangerous since its "unknown". What should I do in order to prevent this from happening
???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Windows detect that the installer has an unknown origin, the Windows Defender Smartscreen blocks this kind of executable.

If you want to eliminate this problem, I suggest you to apply a digital signature with your information to the executable. In this case, Windows doesn't raise the Defender Smartscreen on its start.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should disable Windows Defender SmartScreen: [How to do it](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-fix-app-has-been-blocked-your-protection-windows-10).
Also you can sign your .exe file in order to prevent Windows Defender SmartScreen from blocking your app.